# .Net PictureBox image displaying very slowly but loading fast

Tags: .net, vb.net, picturebox

I'm using VB.NET to load images from a URL into a PictureBox control using LoadAsync. These are often very small images - sometimes 76x76 pixels. The delay in displaying them onscreen is extreme. I initially thought it was due to load time, but I added a log to the LoadComplete event and found that the image took 0.29 seconds to load but an additional 21 seconds (per my stopwatch) to display.

```
Public Sub ShowImage(ByRef image As PictureBox, imgUrl as String)
    Log("Starting to load image")
    AddHandler image.LoadCompleted, ImgFinish(image)
    image.Image = Nothing
    image.CancelAsync()
    image.LoadAsync(imgUrl)
    image.Visible = True

End Sub
Private Function ImgFinish(ByRef image As PictureBox)
    Log("Image loading complete")
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

And the log output:

```
(17:03:59.930) vb_Utilities.ShowImage[697] - V:Starting to load image
(17:04:00.220) vb_Utilities.ImgFinish[731] - Image loading complete
```

Then using a stopwatch I timed 21 additional seconds - to 17:25 - before the image appeared)

I also tried adding image.Refresh() to the function ImgFinish thinking that perhaps it just wasn't redrawing, but that didn't help.

What could be causing this delay? What can I check or try?

Comment: No idea on the problem, but you should change the signature of `ImgFinish` to match the event. See: [PictureBox.LoadCompleted Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadcompleted?view=net-5.0#examples).

Comment: changing the handler to "Addressof ImgFInish" stacks handlers - that is every time it's called it re-adds the handler for the event so eventually ImgFinish is called 100 times or more.  For a reason that I don't really know, calling the function this way executes it only once

Comment: "it re-adds the handler for the event so eventually ImgFinish is called 100 times or more....calling the function this way executes it only once" - Solving a problem caused by a poor coding decision with some hack is not a good idea.  Only add the handler once in either the constructor or OnLoad method.  Alternatively, add it as you are currently doing, but remove it in `ImgFinish`.

Comment: I literally only added it to record the timestamp for LoadComplete. It's not part of my solution and I'm deleting it once I figure out why the picture appears 21 seconds after it's loaded